# Retrieve PHP session set in image file

Tags: php, image, session

I have a HTML form that is sent to a PHP page to process. I need to add a captcha to the form. I cannot change the HTML page to PHP and so have set a session in a captcha.php page which outputs as an image. When the page loads the session var is set but I cannot retrieve this session in the process PHP page, the session is empty. Can anyone assist?

Code that sets session in the captcha.php:

```
session_start(); // start a session
$image = imagecreate(50, 20); //create blank image (width, height)
$bgcolor = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0); //add background color with RGB.
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255); //add text/code color with RGB.
$code = rand(1000, 9999); //create a random number between 1000 and 9999
$_SESSION['code'] = $code; //add the random number to session 'code'
imagestring($image, 10, 8, 3, $_SESSION['code'], $textcolor); //create image with all the settings above.
header ("Content-type: image/png"); // define image type
imagepng($image); //display image as PNG
```

PHP process page:

```
session_start();

print_r($_SESSION);
```

Can anyone assist?

Comment: as per usual with sessions that don't "stick": make sure the session cookie's persisting, make sure it's set correctly, make sure the session ID remains constant in all your scripts (unless you change it yourself), etc... Make sure the session_start() actually works, and isn't being killed by premature output-ulation.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
print_r($_SESSION['code']);
```